# Email addresses from Excel cell returns the message that the address is invalid

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I created an Excel macro that generates e-mails using a template and saves it in draft folders so it can be sent by a member of my team.

When it's time to send the message, it returns the message that the address is invalid.
The address is correct. Filling it manually the e-mail is sent.

```vb
Sub create_email()

Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim OutAccount As Outlook.Account

For linha = 2 To 16
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(' .oft file path)
    Set OutAccount = OutApp.Session.Accounts.Item(2)
    With OutMail
        .To = Cells(linha, 1).Value
        .CC = ' CC address
        .BCC = ' BCC address
        .Subject = ' text  & Cells(linha, 2)
        strFile = ""
        strFile = Dir(" ' file path ")  
        If strFile <> "" Then
            .Attachments.Add (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Base - " & Cells(linha, 2).Value & ".xlsx")
            .SendUsingAccount = OutAccount
            .Save
          Else
            GoTo Fim
        End If
Fim:
        
    End With
Next

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
Set OutAccount = Nothing
End Sub
```

The code runs into this issue for every e-mail address. If I change it for a contact name group, it creates the same issue.

All e-mails appear in the draft folder correctly separated.

Comment: As you don't qualify `Cells`, code will access data from the active sheet - is that what you intend? Double checked (eg by using the debugger)  that `Cells(linha, 1)` contains the expected address?

Comment: If you have verified that `Cells(linha, 1)` contains the expected address as FunThomas has suggested, try casting the datatype to string:  `.To = CStr(Cells(linha, 1).Value)`

Comment: Hello! Just to clarify, yes the comand with `Cells(linha, 1)` is intended to capture the info in the active sheet. 

Anyway, I've tried the CStr command suggested but it still doesn't work. It says the e-mail wasn't found on the database. For some odd reason they return the emails are invalid despite the addresses being correct

Answer (score 0):

[ResolveAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Recipients.ResolveAll) may trigger an address update.

Note: The test in the example in the link applies when the recipient is **not** in email address format.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub create_email()

    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutAccount As Outlook.Account
    Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
    
    Dim myRecipients As Outlook.Recipients
    'Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
    
    Dim linha As Long
    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutAccount = OutApp.Session.Accounts.Item(1)
    Debug.Print OutAccount
    
    For linha = 2 To 16
    
        'Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(" .oft file path")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        
        With OutMail
        
            .To = Cells(linha, 1).Value
            .Subject = "Test " & linha
            
            Set myRecipients = OutMail.Recipients
            
            ' May trigger an address update
            myRecipients.ResolveAll
            
            ' Not for email address format. Resolved always True.
            '  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Recipients.ResolveAll
            '
            'If Not myRecipients.ResolveAll Then
            '    For Each myRecipient In myRecipients
            '        If Not myRecipient.Resolved Then
            '            MsgBox myRecipient.Name
            '        End If
            '        Set myRecipient = Nothing
            '    Next
            'End If
            
            .Save
            '.Send
            
        End With
        
        Set OutMail = Nothing
        
    Next
    
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Set OutAccount = Nothing
    
    Set myRecipients = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks a lot. Turns out the suggested ResolveAll solved the issue. At least, when sending the e-mails they don't turn a message of not existing and sending them doesn't turn an auto-response of "could not send the item".